# Asio without boost safety multithreading

Tags: c++, asio

I want to use asio wthout boost.
Asio tutorial has such example https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.2/doc/asio/tutorial/tuttimer5/src.html

```
class printer
{
public:
  printer(asio::io_context& io)
    : strand_(asio::make_strand(io)),
      timer1_(io, asio::chrono::seconds(1)),
      timer2_(io, asio::chrono::seconds(1)),
      count_(0)
  {
    timer1_.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(strand_,
          boost::bind(&printer::print1, this)));

    timer2_.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(strand_,
          boost::bind(&printer::print2, this)));
  }
private:
  asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
  asio::steady_timer timer1_;
  asio::steady_timer timer2_;
  int count_;
};
```

I try to do it without boost, but I don't know how to replace `asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;`
I don't know how to synchronising handlers in multithreaded programs. Could you advise some sites about asio without boost.

Answer (score 0):

The only boost header in example:

```
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
```

Remove it and replace the boost::bind by std::bind:

```
#include <functional>
timer1_.async_wait(asio::bind_executor(strand_,
      std::bind(&printer::print1, this)));
```